# How to use classifiers

Tags: matlab

I want to use the svm, knn, adaboost classifier on my data features. I build up code where I calculated the frame differences and calculated the features ([eigenvalues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors), strain energy, potential energy).... build up an array of [number of frames , features]. I try to use svm as:

```
 Features = data;  % Features array [40, 5]
 class = ones(numFrames-1, 1);  % numFrames=41
 class(1:(fix(numFrames/2))) = -1;
 SVMstruct = svmtrain(Features, class, 'Kernel_Function', 'rbf');
 newclass = svmclassify(SVMstruct, [40 5]);  %Test data
```

I got an error:

> The number of columns in TEST and training data must be equal.
>
> %classperf(cp,newclass); %performance of the class given by cp'`

What is the reason for this error? And how do I to use further classifiers with this features set?

Comment: Could you provide the size of the Features matrix?

Comment: Features matrix  is [40,5]

Comment: To clarify, is that `Features=[40, 5]` or `size(Features) = [40,5]`?

Comment: i build up an array of size [ 40 5]....in which i calculate the 5 set of features of particular frame...i run the video over 40 frames and calculate the features for each frames....then i have to apply svm approach over it....i jst found the error in line 'newclass'....in mathworks forum svmclassify should have sample data  columns same to training data...therfore in sample data i`ll just put array of [40 5]....need clarification about sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can infer following things from the error which you are getting.

There is no error in `svmtrain` that means `size(features)=[40 5]`. The error is in the last line. See the syntax of `svmclassify`. You pass a sample of test data which has same number of features/columns as the training data in your case 5). Instead you are passing the size which is `[40 5]` which has only two columns. Pass the actual test set of `n` rows and `5` columns. The last line should be

```
newclass= svmclassify(SVMstruct,testData); %where size(testData)=[n 5], n indicates how many test samples you have.
```

Comment: parag sir @ i have big confusion over test data aur training data....features are my training data which is [40 5] in which i calculate the 5 set of features of particular frame...i run the video over 40 frames and calculate the features for each frames...sir pls explain what should be my test data/samples now....n should take any value b/w 1 to 40

Comment: Can you get access to more video frames similar to your training data? If yes, calculate the 5 sets of features on those frames and use it as testing data. If no, then select RANDOM subset (maybe 5-10 randomly selected frames) and use it as testing data. Calculate 5 sets of features on each frame of testing data. Number of columns in your training and testing data should be same at all time assuming rows in your matrix represent the video frames at different time interval.

Comment: sir i tried like this %sampledata= Features((3:8),(1:5));
newclass= svmclassify(SVMstruct,sampledata);.......this would again show me error..."Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
Error in svmclassify (line 140)
outclass = glevels(outclass(~unClassified),:);
Error in Untitled411111111111 (line 225)
newclass= svmclassify(SVMstruct,sampledata); .sir accrdng to u i jst choose frames 3:8 from same video and use their features values to make sampledata/training data....this method is good aur i have to calculate the values from another video.

Comment: sir i also tried this---                                Features=data(21:40,3:4);class= ones(20,1);                    class(1:(fix(24/2))) =-1;                                      SVMstruct = svmtrain(Features,class,'Kernel_Function','rbf'); newclass= svmclassify(SVMstruct,[5 2]);.....this time my column lenth is same ...bt error occurs......""Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Error in svmclassify (line 140)
    outclass = glevels(outclass(~unClassified),:);

Error in Untitled411111111111 (line 227)
 newclass= svmclassify(SVMstruct,[5 2]); %where

Comment: I saw `svmclassify` function too. I cannot understand the source of the error. The error means that it cotains zero or negative element in a vector. Also, a vector which is used for indexing can contain zero only if it it a logical vector. You can post your entire code by editing your question or post a new question.

Comment: parag sir i clear out my problems with svm classify ....but now im facing problems in checking performance of my classifier......my code--[training]=xlsread('ashish22.xls');
[sample]=xlsread('ashish33.xls');
class = ones(78,1);%equal to training row
class(1:(fix(78/2))) = -1;
SVMstruct = svmtrain(training,class);
newclass= svmclassify(SVMstruct,sample); 
CP=classperf(class,newclass);error in this line
CP.CorrectRate 
error is ---The classifier output CLASSOUT does not have the same size as the ground truth and there was not any TESTIDX provided.
pls help me..this complete my submission

Comment: Check if sample has 78 elements. I guess it doesn't and that's what the error says. `The classifier output CLASSOUT does not have the same size as the ground truth`. Let me know.

Comment: but sir our test data should be less than training data always .....sample is my test data......im also not clear with this line "there was not any TESTIDX provided."....78 by 5 array is my training data and sample array of 39 by 5 is training data

Comment: do you mean sample data which is `39x5` is your test data? If yes, then you should provide true labels for the test data to evaluate the performance. In that case, your `class` argument should be `39x1` and not `78x1`. Its simple, if the test data is 100 elements, I classify them and tell you to test the performance, what is the only thing you will need? True labels of those 100 elements right?

Comment: kk sir i build like dis and got the ans of performance ....dats wht ur saying or i do some mistakes [training]=xlsread('ashish22.xls');

[sample]=xlsread('ashish33.xls');

 traininglabel = ones(78,1);
 
traininglabel(1:(fix(78/2))) = 0;
testlabel=ones(39,1);
testlabel(1:(fix(39/2))) = 0;
cp= classperf(traininglabel);
SVMstruct = svmtrain(training,traininglabel);
newclass= svmclassify(SVMstruct,sample);cp=classperf(testlabel,newclass);
get(cp)

Comment: Yes, this looks correct. But why do you have same names for training and testing performance i.e. `cp`?

Comment: kkk sir thanks for the help.......sir im thinking of plotting graph of each frame recognition rate vs number of frames ....i kept my no of frames 40 for each video that i run ....i use 20 videos for training and 5 videos for testing ...using class performance which gives me the final anw .....can i get plot of each frame possible???

Comment: Each frame will be either classified as either 1 or -1. Class performance will give you the average recognition rate. What do you mean by plot frame recognition rate vs frames?

Comment: sir like dat in x axis no of frames which in my case would be 40 in y axis recognition rate percentage....when i use svm classifier it gives recognition rate for testing data......this type of plot .........and sir in knn classifier our training data arrangement of row columns changes ..in rows data features columns no of observation and training label would be same as the no of columns of  observation ans same my testing arrangement....

Comment: Thats what I am saying... when you plot frame index on x-axis, what will you plot on y-axis, its just going to be 1 or -1. From where does the frame recognition rate come from. You can plot recognition rate when you have multiple frames, maybe you can do it for video.

Comment: kk sir can i get scatter plot for more tham 2 dimensional just like showplot command use in sv train

Comment: sir my recognition rate comes out to very low even i use same video for training and testing

Comment: Check the SVM parameters. Also post a new question if you have more questions as this discussion is getting too long.