# how to use svm classifier in feature extraction

Tags: matlab, svm

i calculated the 5 features for a video ..run this video for 40 frames ...40 by 5 array constructed...for making my training data i calculated features for 20 videos ...20*[ 40 by 5]    ...while making group i have some issues...class 1 and 0 assigned to each row of training data like 800 rows half 1 and ohter half 0....or assigning related to single block of 40 by 5 like 20 rows ....and another problem in calculating class performance where term defined as "true label"....CP = classperf(truelabels, classout)....classout an array that updates the its value over true labels ...but truelabels is an array of 1 and 0 of same length of testing data?????

Comment: Could you please invest 5 minutes to ask a somehow readable question? You should if you expect anybody to answer this...

Comment: I thought your doubts were solved in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913185/how-to-use-classifiers) question. Also, please do not ask question as if you are talking to somebody. I know this is an assignment/project so write a question as if you are writing report.

Comment: Also, `truelabels` will be the training labels, if you obtained `classout` by predicting train samples, and it will be testing labels if you obtained `classout` by predicting test samples. Read the documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/classperf.html)

Comment: parag sir sorry for readable type ...but yhis not my assignment or project...im doing for this my satisfication ..im nowwhere near pattern machine subject it nt my course but i want to do it ....

Comment: But what is your question?

Comment: It might be a good idea to first work through classifying some of the supplied data sets (like Fisher Irises) before trying to solve your problem. Then you need a clear statement of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is about how to use these matlab functions:

- http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/stats/svmtrain.html
- http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/stats/svmclassify.html
- http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/bioinfo/ref/classperf.html

If you are trying to classify entire videos you will have one label per video, i.e. assign 1 or 0 to "single block of 40 by 5 like 20 rows", In which case your Training data matrix should be 20x200 (20 videos with 200 features) and you will have a 20x1 Group label vector.

If you are trying to classify individual frames in each video your Training data matrix should be 800x5 (800 frames of 5 features) and you will have a 800x1 Group label vector.

According to classperf documentation:
"classout must contain the same number of elements as truelabels."
It also has a good example of how to use classperf.

Comment: sir thanks for understanding my question ...therfore truelabel would be  mine group vector arrangement